# Audio device: Nvidia corporation usage

Tags: audio, nvidia

I am using Ubuntu 18.04. Whenever I execute:
**lspci -v | grep -i audio**

It returns:

**37:00.1 Audio device: NVIDIA Corporation Device 10f8 (rev a1)**

In my sound settings,instead of showing any speakers or builtin speakers information, I noticed a **Dummy Output** as sound output device. Can anyone help me out that how to use the NVIDIA Corporation Driver audio device?

Kind Regards,